# How to call a specific method of a tasklet

Tags: spring-batch

In a job context there are an 'method' parameter so a could call directly an tasklet method as said in the documentation "If the tasklet is specified as a bean definition, then a method can be specified and a POJO will be adapted to the Tasklet interface. The method suggested should have the same arguments as Tasklet.execute (or a subset), and have a compatible return type (boolean, void or RepeatStatus)." I declared a bean

```
    <step id="carregaStep" next="iniciaStep">
        <tasklet ref="atividadesTasklet" method="carregaAtividades"/>
    </step>
```

I declared a bean that extends Tasklet and I implement an method:

```
public RepeatStatus carregaAtividades(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception
```

But this method is not called.

I try to search an exemplo of use in google, but it's dificult since 'method' in a common word and google cannot search pontuation, like a search for "method=" and "tasklet". Someone could give me an example of use of a method of tasklet?

```
<bean id="atividadesTasklet" class="br.mypackage.AtividadesTasklet" scope="step" />



public class AtividadesTasklet implements Tasklet{

    public RepeatStatus carregarAtividades(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;   
    }


    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }   
}


    <step id="carregaAtividadesStep" >
        <tasklet ref="atividadesTasklet" method="carregarAtividades">

        </tasklet>
    </step>
```

Comment: I believe (I have to double check) the method parameter does not allow parameters...

Comment: but documentation says: "The method suggested should have the same arguments as Tasklet.execute (or a subset), and have a compatible return type". its like a Tasklet.execute method, isn't it? So it should have the same parameters. Besides that I need to access the context from this method. I try whitout parameters and receive this exception:

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: target class must declare a method with matching name and parameter types

Comment: Can you provide the definition of `atividadesTasklet`?

Comment: I edit the original post and add the definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug.  The configuration style you're using:

```
<tasket ref="myTasklet" method="myMethod"/>
```

is a shorthand way of configuring the `MethodInvokingTaskletAdapter`.  However, that adapter does not pass on the parameters.  If your method takes no parameters it works.  I've logged issue [BATCH-2397](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2397) to track this.

That being said, if you're willing to implement a method that matches the signature of `Tasklet#execute`, then I'd recommend just implementing the `Tasklet` interface and skipping this overhead in the first place.

Comment: In case we use spring batch version 2.1.9, I don't know if it was a bug if it was corrected.

Comment: My testing was using 3.0.4...the latest.

Comment: @MichaelMinella - Can you please guide here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65507138/how-can-we-take-the-result-of-methodinvokingtaskletadapter-as-a-reader-in-the ?