# How can we take the result of `MethodInvokingTaskletAdapter` as a reader in the Spring Batch Step?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

How can we take the result of `MethodInvokingTaskletAdapter` as a reader in the Spring Batch Step? Reference - https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/index-single.html#taskletStep and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/pull/567

Here is the code that I developed

**JobConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    @Bean
    public CustomService service() {
        return new CustomService();
    }
    
    @StepScope
    @Bean
    public MethodInvokingTaskletAdapter methodInvokingTasklet() {
        MethodInvokingTaskletAdapter methodInvokingTaskletAdapter = new MethodInvokingTaskletAdapter();
        methodInvokingTaskletAdapter.setTargetObject(service());
        methodInvokingTaskletAdapter.setTargetMethod("getEmployees");
        return methodInvokingTaskletAdapter;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Job methodInvokingJob() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("methodInvokingJob")
                .start(methodInvokingStep())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step methodInvokingStep() {
        // Looking to configure the Chunk based Step here, dont know how to do using MethodInvokingTaskletAdapter
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("methodInvokingStep")
                .tasklet(methodInvokingTasklet())
                .build();
    }
}
```

**CustomService.java**

```
public class CustomService {
    public void serviceMethod(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
    
    public void invokeMethod() {
        System.out.println("=============== Your method has executed !");
    }
    
    public List<Employee> getEmployees(){
        // In real world, it will be an GET API call to XYZ system
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
        employees.add(Employee.builder().firstName("Ravi").lastName("Shankar").email("ravi.shankar@gmail.com").age(30).build());
        employees.add(Employee.builder().firstName("Parag").lastName("Rane").email("parag.rane@gmail.com").age(11).build());
        employees.add(Employee.builder().firstName("Priya").lastName("Pande").email("priya.pande@gmail.com").age(40).build());
        employees.add(Employee.builder().firstName("Kiran").lastName("khot").email("kiran.khot@gmail.com").age(50).build());
        return employees;
    }
}
```

Employee.java

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Employee {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private int age;
}
```

MethodInvokingTaskletApplication.java

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@SpringBootApplication
public class MethodInvokingTaskletApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MethodInvokingTaskletApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code seems fine. I tested in my Dev environment and is working.  Could you add a System.out.println in your service method   public List<Employee> getEmployees(). Its executing perfectly. I can share the tested github URL if required

Comment: Can you please answer on my original query - output of `MethodInvokingTaskletAdapter ` configured as reader in a chunk based processing step?

Comment: We can get the output from the Tasklet but in the question a comment saying to read as "Chunk based Step here". Tasklet is a single task to execute and not continuous chunk. Please let me know application requires output only of MethodInvokingTaskletAdapter to call in a custom reader  or to build chunk based reader processor and writer.

Comment: Yes right, this particular step expects input of data from the `MethodInvokingTaskletAdapter` output and simply process this data as a chunk based step

Comment: Please let me know below approach can be used for your business. Create a customer reader and call service method inside that and you can control the job as required. This will  avoid coupling the tasklet and chunk together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, you can't. The `MethodInvokingTaskletAdapter` is meant to adapt a POJO to a `Tasklet`. We have an `ItemReaderAdapter` that you can use to adapt a POJO to an `ItemReader`. You can read about it in the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/adapter/ItemReaderAdapter.html

Now you'll have an issue with your service as configured in that each call to the delegating POJO is considered an item. That means that your item as configured will be a `List<Employee>` instead of just an `Employee`. Given your configuration states it's not the real service, I'll assume that your real service should return an `Employee` per call and `null` once the results are exhausted.

To update your configuration (with your service as it is configured in your question) in your sample:

```
...
    @StepScope
    @Bean
    public ItemReaderAdapter itemReader() {
        ItemReaderAdapter reader = new ItemReaderAdapter();
        reader.setTargetObject(service());
        reader.setTargetMethod("getEmployees");
        return reader;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Job methodInvokingJob() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("methodInvokingJob")
                .start(methodInvokingStep())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step methodInvokingStep() {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("methodInvokingStep")
                .<List<Employee>, List<Employee>>chunk(methodInvokingTasklet())
                .reader(itemReader())
                // You'll need to define a writer...
                .writer(itemWriter())
                .build();
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I request you to be answering great solutions on all batch questions. Please.

Comment: @Michael  In the reader chunk  tasklet is getting called it may be a typo or I am missing something. Please advise  .<List<Employee>, List<Employee>>chunk(methodInvokingTasklet())

Comment: @Michael - Code is not working `The parameterized method <List<Employee>, List<Employee>>chunk(int) of type StepBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (MethodInvokingTaskletAdapter)`. The API is going to return the list of employees  only. Looks like its not achievable in Spring Batch though

Comment: If the service returns a `List` but you need the `ItemReader` to return each item within the list, Spring Batch does not provide a component to do this adapting. You'll have to write a simple adapter yourself. You can utilize our `AbstractPagingItemReader` as the base of that custom reader since each call to the service is essentially a page (assuming that the list is not all inclusive on a single call). If it is all inclusive in a single call, you could (in theory) just use a `ListItemReader` and call the service on startup to populate the list.  Just a thought.